# CAPL: dynamically changing of CAN ID request to ECU

Tags: capl, canoe

I would need to change CAN ID request to ECU during the test. I know only one option how to do it, just to create as many Diagnostic Consoles as I need with different CAN IDs but it it quite annoying.

e.g.,
I would need to send one request from CAN ID 29-bit identifier 0xWWXXYYZZ and then from 11-bit identifier 0xXXY or 29-bit 0xWWXXYYTT
Is there any CAPL function how to change CAN ID dynamically?

Comment: Are you talking about sending diagnostic requests (sent by 'diagSendRequest') or plain CAN messages (sent by 'output')?

Comment: I mean diagnostic requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the configuration which is done in the "Diagnostic/ ISO TP" via CAPL. Since there is no real use case for this kind of behavior, it is not implemented (is my assumption). 
But if you really need to change the IDs of diagnostic requests and responses, you can make use of the OSEK_TP.DLL to send your requests. There are CAPL functions in that dll which you can use to change the request and response IDs.